# What's the best stats to use for pre/post data?

Tags: group-differences, categorical-data

I have 107 participants and had them do 2 lessons.  Before lesson one, I asked 5 knowledge questions with true/false response for each. After the second lesson, I administered the same survey questions with the same 5 true/false knowledge questions. I coded the data in SPSS (1 is true; 2 is false).  How do I go about analyzing whether there was a difference in their knowledge? t-tests?